# Create a distance matrix from Pandas Dataframe using a bespoke distance function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matrix, distance, adjacency-matrix

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns, "id" (a unique identifier) and "date", that looks as follows:

```
test_df.head()

    id  date
0   N1  2020-01-31
1   N2  2020-02-28
2   N3  2020-03-10
```

I have created a custom Python function that, given two date strings, will compute the absolute number of days between those dates (with a given date format string e.g. %Y-%m-%d), as follows:

```py
def days_distance(date_1, date_1_format, date_2, date_2_format):
    """Calculate the number of days between two given string dates

    Args:
        date_1 (str): First date
        date_1_format (str): The format of the first date
        date_2 (str): Second date
        date_2_format (str): The format of the second date

    Returns:
        The absolute number of days between date1 and date2
    """

    date1 = datetime.strptime(date_1, date_1_format)
    date2 = datetime.strptime(date_2, date_2_format)
    return abs((date2 - date1).days)
```

I would like to create a distance matrix that, for all pairs of IDs, will calculate the number of days between those IDs. Using the `test_df` example above, the final time distance matrix should look as follows:

```
    N1    N2    N3
N1  0     28    39
N2  28    0     11
N3  39    11    0
```

I am struggling to find a way to compute a distance matrix using a bespoke distance function, such as my `days_distance()` function above, as opposed to a standard distance measure provided for example by SciPy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `pdist` time distance matrix can be easily generated without applying a custom function..Not sure why you need to apply custom function here..Any specific reason?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSharma thanks for the reply. If I can do it without a custom function, that is ok, but would you be able to provide an example of how I can use ```pdist``` to transform my dataframe into a time distance matrix please? Reading the pdist documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html, I can't see an in-built metric that would explicitly calculate time distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) + [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform) to create a square distance matrix representing the pair wise differences between the datetime objects, finally create a new dataframe from this square matrix:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

i, d = test_df['id'].values, pd.to_datetime(test_df['date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(d[:, None])), dtype='timedelta64[ns]', index=i, columns=i)
```

Alternatively you can also calculate the distance matrix using `numpy` broadcasting:

```
i, d = test_df['id'].values, pd.to_datetime(test_df['date']).values 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(d[:, None] - d), index=i, columns=i)
```

---

```
        N1      N2      N3
N1  0 days 28 days 39 days
N2 28 days  0 days 11 days
N3 39 days 11 days  0 days
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, that is fantastic, thank you so much! I'm not familiar with ```pdist``` nor ```squareform```, so this really helps my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Glad i could be of help :)..One more thing if you need numerical values in dataframe instead of `timedelta` values you can simply divide the dataframe `df` by `pd.Timedelta(days=1)` i.e `df / pd.Timedelta(days=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date column to datetime format. Then create numpy array from the column. Then create a matrix with the array repeated 3 times. Then subtract the matrix with its transpose. Then convert the result to a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['N1', 'N2', 'N3'],
                    'date': ['2020-01-31', '2020-02-28', '2020-03-10']})
test_df['date_datetime'] = test_df.date.apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))

date_array = np.array(test_df.date_datetime)

date_matrix = np.tile(date_array, (3,1))
date_diff_matrix = np.abs((date_matrix.T - date_matrix))

date_diff = pd.DataFrame(date_diff_matrix)
date_diff.columns = test_df.ID
date_diff.index = test_df.ID

>>> ID  N1      N2       N3
    ID          
    N1  0 days  28 days 39 days
    N2  28 days 0 days  11 days
    N3  39 days 11 days 0 days
```